# Please what does func() mean in python when used inside a function

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

Please what does func() mean in python when used inside a function,For example in the code below.

```
def identity_decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        func()
    return wrapper
```

Comment: you're calling a function that was passed as an argument in `identity_decorator`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`func` is an argument given to the function `identity_decorator()`.

The expression `func()` means "call the function assigned to the variable `func`."

The decorator is taking another function as an argument, and returning a new function (defined as `wrapper`) which executes the given function `func` when it is run.

[Here is some information about decorators.](https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-python-decorators/)

Answer (score 17):

I was wondering the same! You can see how it works with the follow example:

```
def make_pretty(func):
    def inner():
       print("I got decorated")
       func()
    return inner

def ordinary():
    print("I am ordinary")

pretty = make_pretty(ordinary)
pretty()

Output
I got decorated
I am ordinary
```

Now when you remove the func() and you try to rerun it:

```
def make_pretty(func):
    def inner():
       print("I got decorated")
    return inner

def ordinary():
    print("I am ordinary")

pretty = make_pretty(ordinary)
pretty()

Output
I got decorated
```

**You see the the decorated function was not called**. Please have a look here https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator