# Creating images from a string of random functions

Tags: python, image, recursion, python-imaging-library

I've rewritten a bit of what was done [here](http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/generating-abstract-images-with-random-functions/) in an attempt to not have to use recursion so as to produce the images. While I can get what appears to be the correct string of random functions, I am unable to get the correct output arrays so as to build the image.

You'll notice I've put the xVar function first in the random functions because it will operate on an empty string and give me back values. This is similar to what the original code does except that (by recursion) uses the value 0 to pick out one of three functions that will operate on empty strings. I am thinking that the results are passed back in so that functions such as np.sin will work.

I think the issue might lie in my usage of the [identity decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219439/please-what-does-func-mean-in-python-when-used-inside-a-function/27219457#:%7E:text=func%20is%20an%20argument%20given,func%20when%20it%20is%20run.) func(*testlist), perhaps I'm using it incorrectly.

```
import numpy as np, random
from PIL import Image
width, height = 256,256
xArray = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, width).reshape((1, width, 1))
yArray = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, height).reshape((height, 1, 1))

def xVar(): return xArray
def yVar(): return yArray

def safeDivide(a, b): return np.divide(a, np.maximum(b, 0.001))

def add(x,y):
    added = np.add(x, y)
    return added

def Color():
    randColorarray = np.array([random.random(), random.random(), random.random()]).reshape((1, 1, 3))
    return randColorarray

# def circle(x,y):
#     circles = (x- 100) ** 2 + (y - 100) ** 2
#     return circles


functions = (Color, xVar, yVar, np.sin, np.multiply, safeDivide)

depth = 5

def functionArray(depth = 0):
    FunctList = []
    FunctList.append(xVar)
    for x in range(depth):
        func = random.choice(functions)
        FunctList.append(func)
    return FunctList

def ImageBuilder():
    FunctionList = functionArray(depth)
    testlist = []
    for func in FunctionList:
        values = func(*testlist)
    return values


vals = ImageBuilder()


repetitions = (int(xArray / vals.shape[0]), int(yArray / vals.shape[1]), int(3 / vals.shape[2]))
img = np.tile(vals, repetitions)

# Convert to 8-bit, send to PIL and save
img8Bit = np.uint8(np.rint(img.clip(0.0, 1.0) * 255.0))
Image.fromarray(img8Bit).save('Images/' + '.png', "PNG")
```

Depending on which random function is chosen, I'll either get

values = func(*testlist)
ValueError: invalid number of arguments

or

TypeError: safeDivide() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'

- Note however that the linked program does not get a safe divide error and both a and b are not being explicitly passed in (as is the same with np.multiply).
  Thanks for any help.

Comment: could you explicitly say what is the problem and question? which result are you expecting?

Comment: @Stepan I added the errors I'm getting.

Comment: the problem of your code exactly as error massage says, because you try to pass 0 arguments to function safeDivide(a,b) which require 2 arguments as must. in original code the number of arguments was adjusted for each function by args = [buildImg(depth + 1) for n in range(nArgs)]. If you explain what you want to obtain as a final result I can try to help you to fix it

Comment: @Stepan I think I understand a little more in that because of the recursive nature arguments with 0 inputs are fed in to those with 1 input and two of those outputs are used in functions with 2 inputs. That the recursive nature takes care of this. I was trying to make a non-recursive sequential implementation so as to have more control about what functions are used as inputs as I'd like to be able to reproduce the same types of images; with the linked implementation functions are chosen randomly. So how might I add some control, either sequentially or recursively? Thanks.